# Правильное указание путей к файлам

Tags: laravel, path

Давно уже мучает этот вопрос,но никак пока толком не могу понять где правильно указывать путь '/' а где '\'.Вот сейчас на Laravel столкнулся с данной проблемой

```
Route::get('/admin', 'Admin/AdminController@index'); - выдает ошибку
Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\AdminController@index'); - работает
```

Так же самое и в Codigniter одна функция возаращает путь как `root/folder/file` другая `roote\foolder\file` в чем разница поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы путаете путь к файлу и namespace класса. В данном случае `Admin\AdminController` - это класс `AdminController` в namespace `Admin`

Comment: Я думал namespace это такой же путь который указывает откуда стоит подключать классы

Answer (score 1):

[Определение namespace](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29), [статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/212773/), [еще статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/132736/)